# Convert unicode to ISO 8859-2 in .net

Tags: asp.net, encoding, character-encoding, escaping

Im messing a lot with encoding stuff. I see UTF-8, Unicode, Latin, ISO, RTC, etc... But i dont understand the relation between them.

How could i convert from Unicode to ISO 8859-2?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: ISO 8859-2 is another name for Latin-2 if that helps

Comment: Oblig [link](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to Joels' unicode article

Comment: Thanks, now i understand more.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx)

```
Encoding iso88592encoder = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2"); // by name
// or
Encoding iso88592encoder = Encoding.GetEncoding(28592); // by Windows code page number
byte[] encodedBytes = iso88592encoder.GetBytes(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class to convert from on encoding to another.